# Handling error messages from dll in custom dialog without aborting installation - Basic MSI -Installshield 2012

Tags: windows-installer, installshield-2012, basic-msi

I am using Installshield 2012 to build a basic msi installer , Here I have a custom dialog where i get the user inputs which are then passed to a dll for validation . The dll returns 0 or 1 based on the success or failure and in case of failure it also gives a msgbox.

The problem is that after clicking ok in the message box the installation is aborted . Is there anyway to throw the msg box without aborting the installation [Similar to a HTML form validation ??]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not return 1 from your validation DLL. Windows Installer interprets this as failure and stops the installation. Always return 0. The correct approach would be to set a property in order to signal if the validation passed.

Comment: It worked !!!! , Caught the function return value and assigned it to a property. While calling a newdialog , i added the condition to check if the return value in the property is a success case or error case and then proceed to next dialog .. Thanks for the help Ciprian